# How to do I use a web proxy with Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, proxy, www-mechanize

I'm trying to use WWW::Mechanize with a proxy server, but seems like I cant get it to work.
Since Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, I've been reading about the proxy thing over
[link text](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.836/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#Proxy_attributes)

I have a list of proxies, for example:

```
74.87.151.157:8000  
69.171.152.25:3128  
190.253.82.253:8080 
189.11.196.221:3128 
41.234.205.201:8080
```

I have no idea how to use them.

Thanks,

Comment: What code have you tried so far ?

Comment: Well,  I just tried what you suggested, and It worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example sets a HTTP-proxy:

```
my $mech  = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $proxy = '74.87.151.157:8000';

$mech->proxy('http', "http://$proxy");
```

Comment: When I use this method I get error: Error GETing http://www.google.com: Not Found at ./my-script.pl line 63